# How to compare form elements in php?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to compare to parts of my registration form, they are password1 and password2.

```
<input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Password">
<input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Retype Password">
```

I am sure it's very simple but I haven't worked with forms much until recently and don't know how to compare these. I want to make php check if password1 and password2 are equal and if not the form button won't show up. I can't figure out how to target them.

```
<?php
if(What goes here?) {
echo "The passwords do not match";
} else {
echo "<input type='submit'>";
}
?>
```

Please help!

Comment: use `empty()` in a conditional statement. Plus, you've quite a few parts missing. Here, have a read http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php and http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: I don't need to know how to encrypt passwords which is what one of the links are for, that is handled in the file that everything is sent to. I am trying to stop the form from sending unless the passwords are the same.

Comment: if you don't need to "hash" passwords (not encrypt), then you already know the risks involved and already have a fair grasp on PHP, right? You should already know about conditional statements. It plays a very big role in PHP.

Comment: you've an answer below, ask them.

Comment: Like I said, I don't do much with forms. Not everyone learns PHP the same way. I have learned it here and there, not in order.

Comment: I've provided you with a solution below, complete with explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing you've tagged this as PHP, am submitting the following as a pure PHP solution.

Firstly, you need a form and specifying a POST method. Forms default to GET if omitted.

Sidenote: You can use a GET method, however sending passwords using that method is unsafe.

```
<form action="your_handler.php" method="post">
    <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Retype Password">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

- Another sidenote: You can use `action=""` if your HTML/PHP are inside the same file.
  It is equivalent to "self".

Then, you need a conditional statement to check if both inputs have not been left empty, so we'll use `empty()` as well as a comparison operator `==` to verify that both inputted values do in fact match.

**your_handler.php**

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['password1']) && !empty($_POST['password2'])){

$pass1 = $_POST['password1'];
$pass2 = $_POST['password2'];

if($pass1 == $pass2){
    echo "Match";
    }

else{
    echo "No match.";
    }

}
```

- You can replace `&&` (AND) by `||` (OR) if you wish.
- `||` - OR checks if one or another was empty.
- `&&` - AND checks if both are empty.

---

Reference(s):

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

it goes like this:

```
<?php
  if($_POST['password1']!=$_POST['password2']) 
   {
    echo "The passwords do not match";
   } 
 else  
   {
    echo "<input type='submit'>";
   } 
?>
```

But PHP is a server-side language, there is no way to check this if your form is not submitted first. From your comment: "I am trying to stop the form from sending unless the passwords are the same.", i can tell what you need is a JavaScript code, which is executed clientside, before the form is submitted that is.

Comment: I tried this, however the button doesn't show up. This says they don't match even when they do.

Comment: The button cannot be shown or displayed in the form unless you query the URL first, which means you have to submit it. What you need is a JavaScript function, not a PHP function. A JavaScript function can hide or display elements on your form without submitting it.

Answer (score 0):

HTML File:

```
<form method="POST" action="example.php">
<input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Password">
<input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Retype Password">
<input type="submit">
```

PHP File (example.php):

```
<?php
if($_POST['password1']!=$_POST['password2'])
    echo "The passwords do not match!!!";
else
    echo "The passwords match.";
?>
```